# Ubuntu Freezes with Core Multi-Processing

Tags: firefox, freeze, intel, performance, cpu

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo P50 laptop.  Immediately, I noticed Firefox would freeze within seconds of opening and, after a while, so would the operating system.  After much troubleshooting, I found out the symptoms disappear when I disable Core Multi-Processing in Bios.  With Hyper-Threading still enabled, I have two CPUs available.  If I was able to enable Core Multi-Processing, I would have eight, which would be more optimal for me.  Is there a way to get the most use out of my processor?

Specs

Hardware Package:  Lenovo P50
**CPU:               i7 Core 6700HQ**
Ram:               16GB @ 2133MHz
Video:             NVIDIA Quadro M1000M
OS:                Ubuntu 20.04

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like an issue involving either your video driver or the driver for your storage device. As you’re using a P50 — a well supported notebook — do you have hardware enablement set? There should be no issues running that machine with all eight threads.

Comment: @Matigo , it's definitely a video driver issue.  I downloaded the appropriate driver from NVIDIA and installed.  And I blacklisted nouveau.  Now, everything works great except my touchpad won't work.  If I un-blacklist nouveau, my touchpad works but firefox crashes and I get system errors.  How do I know if hardware enablement is set?

Comment: One way would be to check `apt-cache`: `sudo apt-cache depends linux-generic-hwe-20.04` 

Comment: linux-generic-hwe-20.04:  Depends: linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:  Depends: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04.   So I re-installed using the install third party dependencies and the same think happened, no mouse.